# nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having some problems with Hibernate and the one-to-one mapping.

My DTO class is like this:

CustomerDTO

```
@Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public class CustomerDTO {
    
        private String nic;
        private String name;
        private String address;
        private String contact;
        private ArrayList<UserDTO> user = new ArrayList<>();
```

UserDTO

```
 @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public class UserDTO {
    
        private String email;
        private String password;
        private String role;
        private String lastLogged;
    }
```

My entity class is like this

Customer

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private String nic;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String contact;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;
```

User

```
@Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    public class User {
        @Id
        private String email;
        private String password;
        private String role;
        private String lastLogged;
    
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "cusNIC", referencedColumnName = "nic", nullable = false)
        private Customer customer;
}
```

CustomerControllerClass

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/v1/customer")
    @CrossOrigin
    public class CustomerController {
        @Autowired
        CustomerService customerService;
    
        @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
        public ResponseEntity saveCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDTO dto){
    
            customerService.saveCustomer(dto);
            StandradResponse success = new StandradResponse(200, "success", null);
            return new ResponseEntity(success, HttpStatus.OK);
    
        }
    
    }
```

CustomerService class

```
  @Transactional
    @Service
    public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
    
        @Autowired
        CustomerRepo customerRepo;
    
        @Autowired
        UserRepo userRepo;
    
        @Autowired
        ModelMapper mapper;
    
        @Override
        public void saveCustomer(CustomerDTO dto) {
           
    
            if(!customerRepo.existsById(dto.getNic())){
    
                Customer customer = mapper.map(dto, Customer.class);
    
                customerRepo.save(customer);
    
                for (UserDTO ud : dto.getUser()){
                    if(!userRepo.existsById(ud.getEmail())){
    
                       
                        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO(ud.getEmail(),ud.getPassword(),ud.getRole(),ud.getLastLogged());
    
                        User user = new User(userDTO.getEmail(), userDTO.getPassword(), userDTO.getRole(), userDTO.getLastLogged(), customer);
                         //User user = mapper.map(userDTO, User.class);
                        userRepo.save(user);
    
                    }else {
    
                        throw  new RuntimeException("Email is already exist!");
                    }
    
                }
    
                
            }else{
    
                throw  new RuntimeException("Customer is already exist!");
    
            }
    
        }
```

I tried to send these Json value Using postman

```
 {
    
      "nic" : "55665v",
      "name" : "anyname",
      "address" : "no 20,56 text",
      "contact" : "54673453",
    
      "user": [{
    
        "email":"text@gmail.com",
        "password":"1234",
        "role":"driver",
        "lastLogged":"sunday"
      }]

}
```

And each time I am calling my function I get

`ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): lk.EasyCarRental.backend.entity.Customer; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): lk.EasyCarRental.backend.entity.Customer`

i do not want to auto generate id. I wont to manually input id

Comment: since you are passing the DTO in the JSON  request. You can manually get the id fields and call the setters for the entities before saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the purpose of `Customer customerNic = customerRepo.findCustomerByNic(dto.getNic());` is, but since you are not showing that, it's hard to say what's going on. Have you tried using just `customer` which you persisted prior to entering the loop instead?